# Evaluate $ \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)(1+y)(x+y)}\,dy dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

> Evaluate $ \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)(1+y)(x+y)}\,dy dx$

We can calculate $\int \frac{1}{(1+x)(x+y)} \,dx= \frac{\ln|x+1| - \ln|x+y|}{y-1}$ but that doesn't make it quite easier. Is there a trick to compute this easier?

Comment: Based on [this Wolfram Alpha attempt](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28%281%2Br+cos+t%29%281%2Br+sin+t%29%28r+sin+t+%2Br+cos+t%29%29+from+t%3D0+to+pi%2F2), it seems that polar coordinates do not help...

Comment: @MikeEarnest [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%5B1%2F%281%2Bx%29*1%2F%281%2By%29*1%2F%28x%2By%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2CInf%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2CInf%7D%5D) knows how to evaluate the double integral directly (and returns $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$)

Comment: @MikeEarnest They want you to go pro ( that means you have to pay for it ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
{\cal J} &\equiv
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\dd x\,\dd y \over
\pars{1 + x}\pars{1 + y}\pars{x + y}}}:\ {\Large ?}.
\end{align}
With the variable changes $\ds{x \equiv 1/a - 1}$ and
$\ds{y \equiv 1/b - 1}$ the above integral becomes
\begin{align}
{\cal J} & = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
{\dd a\,\dd b \over a + b - 2ab} =
\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - b \over b}
{\dd b \over 1 - 2b}
\end{align}
With $\ds{\pars{~1 - 2b = t \implies
b = {1 - t \over 2}~}}$:
\begin{align}
{\cal J} & = \underbrace{\int_{0}^{-1}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t}_{\ds{\pi^{2} \over 12}}\ -\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t}_{\ds{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 6}}}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{\large{\pi^{2} \over 4}} \\&&
\end{align}

Comment: @Integrand I’ll add something later when I come back. I’m leaving right now. Change from (0,1) to (-1/2,1/2) and integrate by parts.

Comment: Very nice approach, that initial substitution is very powerful because it works for a quite a few integrals, in my opinion everything is clear since the substitution $t=1−2x$ turns things easier for the last integral so no need for IBP.

Answer (score 4):

CW because some ideas were taken from other posts, which I have linked to.

I'll integrate first in $y$ and then reduce the problem to a known integral. Using partial fractions, we have$$
\frac{1}{(1+y)(x+y)} = \frac{1}{(x-1)}\left(\frac{1}{1+y}-\frac{1}{x+y}\right)
$$Thus
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x)(1+y)(x+y)} \,dydx 
$$
$$
=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2-1}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+y}-\frac{1}{x+y} \,dydx 
$$
$$
=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2-1}\left(\left.\log\left|\frac{1+y}{x+y}\right|\right|_0^{\infty}\right)\,dx 
$$
$$
=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2-1}\left(-\log\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|\right)\,dx 
$$
$$
=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log|x|}{x^2-1}\,dx 
$$Break into $[0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$ (the function has a removable singularity at $x=1$, is integrable near zero by the MVT and at infinity by direct comparison, so we're good) and enforce the substitution $z=1/x$. You'll see that they are equal; hence it suffices to integrate over $(0,1)$ and double it. This allows us to use the Maclaurin series of log, convergent on $(0,1)$:
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log|x|}{x^2-1}\,dx =2 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{(x+1)(x-1)}\,dx
$$It's a [nice exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2295400) to work out that this last integral gives $\pi^2/8$ by reducing it to $\sum_{n\ge 1}(2n-1)^{-2}$. [More generally,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1375028) we have $\int _0^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{x^2+\alpha^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi\log \alpha}{2\alpha}$, and interpreting $\log(i) = \pi i/2$ gives us $\pi^2/4$, as above.

Comment: in that answer why is it that $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{x^2-1}\,dx =-\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{1+x}\,dx-\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\,dx =\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\,dx-\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\,dx$$

Comment: Partial fractions to split up the denominator. Then IBP on the first one and a substitution $x\mapsto 1-x$ on the second one.